# Convert string to HEX in R

Tags: r, utf-8

I search everywhere for an answer but could not find the right one. I need to convert a string to a specific encoding in R, but was not able to do so:

```
string <- "überhaupt"
```

What I need: "&#xfc;berhaupt"

to following functions I have used so far:

```
textutils::HTMLencode(string) gives:  "&uuml;berhaupt"
utf8::utf8_print(string, utf8 = F) gives:  "\u00fcberhaupt"
iconv(string, from = "windows-1252", "utf-8") gives: "Ã¼berhaupt"
```

It seems that I need the hex Numeric character reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C but I don't know how to convert.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have now found the perfect answer. So it should work on all systems:

```
function(x){
x%>%
str_extract_all(., "[:print:]")%>%
map(.x = ., ~stringi::stri_escape_unicode(.x))%>%
map(.x = ., ~str_replace_all(.x, "\\\\u0*", "&#x" ))%>%
map(.x = ., ~case_when(
str_detect(.x, "&#x") ~ str_c(.x, ";"),
T ~.x))%>%
map(.x =., ~str_c(.x, collapse = ""))%>%
unlist()
}
```

Thanks @MrFlick for your help!

Answer (score 4):

So it looks like you want the "numeric character reference" encoding from that page. I'm not sure if there is a built in function for that, but this is one attempt at writing such a function

```
char_ref_encode <- function(x) {
  cp <- charToRaw(x)
  parts <- rle(cp>127)
  with(parts, {
    starts <- head(cumsum(c(0, lengths)), -1) + 1
    ends <- cumsum(lengths)
    paste0(mapply(function(v, start, end) {
      if (v) {
        paste(sprintf("&#x%02x;", as.numeric(cp[start:end])), collapse="")
      } else {
        intToUtf8(cp[start:end])
      }
    }, values, starts, ends), collapse="")
  })
}

char_ref_encode("überhaupt")
# [1] "&#xfc;berhaupt"
```

The basic idea is to look for all the non-ascii characters and then encoding them with their hex values.

Comment: Thank you verry much. It's nearly perfect, but seems to fail, when more than 2 special characters are in one word:

     char_ref_encode("größten") gives: gr&#xf6df;ten
 but I need: gr&#xf6;&#xdf;ten

Comment: @WaschiWaschoi If that's the output you expect, then I've updated the function

Comment: perfect! thanks so much. I will try to understand what the function does :)

Comment: If i use utf8::as_utf8("größten") the result differs. What needs to be changed to get the exact outcome  gr&#xf6;&#xdf;ten? Backround: I am not shure which operating system other users will use so I think of the as_utf8 as a fallback solution

Comment: Well, the output you gave is only correctly for latin1 encoding (windows default). If that's the output you need, then you need to be sure to encode data as latin1 rather than utf8 (which is the opposite of how most people would do it).